# Failure to convert numpy array to tensor

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN. Initially I was encountering an error regarding array size, so I excluded the images causing this issue. Now, I'm encountering the error "ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type Image).
" when attempting to train my model. Here is my code:

```
new_size = (150, 150)
resized_images = []
car_labels = []

for car_type in car_types:
    folder_path = os.path.join(train_dir, car_type)
    for image in os.listdir(folder_path):
        image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, image)
        image_file = Image.open(image_path)
        resized_image = image_file.resize(new_size)
        resized_array = np.array(resized_image)
        if resized_array.shape == (150, 150, 3):
            resized_images.append(resized_image)
            car_labels.append(car_type)

print("Number of valid images:", len(resized_images))

car_labels = np.array(car_labels).reshape(-1, 1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(car_labels)
y = car_labels
X = np.array(resized_images)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, train_size = .75)

from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

# Define the CNN model architecture
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(196, activation='softmax')  # The number of output nodes should match the number of categories
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=10,
    validation_split=0.2  # Reserve 20% of the training data for validation
)
```

Here is the dataset being used: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jutrera/stanford-car-dataset-by-classes-folder (using the train folder)

I've excluded a good amount of code as it was mostly just exploratory data analysis.